# How to create a UIView with NavigationBar and TabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to introduce in my app a View that will contains both navigation bar and a tab bar at the bottom. View contains a Table View with multiple entries and once user tap on a cell a push segue takes him to another view with details regarding the cell he has previously tapped. If he decides, user can go back to parent view by tapping on 'Back' button of the navigation bar on top. In addition to this, I would like my view to have a tab bar at the bottom with extra tools for the user. So, if he decides to check the 'Creator' of the app, he can by simply tap on 'Creator' TabBarItem at the bottom.

I would like to ask you what is the best way to achieve the above. I have already tried to use UITabBarController combined with UINavigationController. Didn't achieve what I was looking for because I would like the view with the table on it to be independent from the TabBarController and **NOT** a part of it (by part I mean by accessible through tabs).

Do you believe a UINavigationController view with UITabBarView would be a better choice?

**UPDATE**

What I mean by, "independent from the TabBarController and NOT a part of it":

*Once the app loaded, I would like to see my main view (with table) contains Navigation Bar on top and Tab Bar at the bottom. However, I don't want to see the first tab of the Tab Bar selected because my main view will not be accessible through tabs of the Tab Bar but through Navigation Bar. If, for example, I am in Main view and tap on 1st tap, I would like to move to another view that will contains some other info.*

Comment: Can you plz elaborate a little bit on `independent from the TabBarController and NOT a part of it`

Comment: I still don't understand how the "independent" tabs will work. If a user clicks on a tab, how do they get back to the main view? You seem to be trying very hard to make things *not* work as standard, but users prefer things to work in the standard, consistent way.

Comment: Hmm, yes seems you are right. I will try to re-think my design for this app. Getting complicated day-by-day

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**:-

Create a tab bar Controller and on that TabbarController assign your navigation Views.
say nav1 with tab1 , nav2 with tab2...

**Option 2**:-

Create a Navigation View Controller and than add the tabbarcontroller on that navigationView Controller by using addSubView.

So when the user clicks on a row in a table u will go to a different View which doesn't have the TabbarController and when the user comes back he will again see the TabbarController.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for quick response. The option 1 seems that will not fit on my needs as I don't want my navigation views to be accessible through tab1, tab2 .. These tabs will contain different 'extra' views. Option 2 seems OK. However, I can't add TabBarController using Storyboard on UINavigationController.

Comment: but u didnt mentioned about the storyboard in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I will do:

First I will subclass UITabbarController and create for example ParentTabBarController. This controller will contain all the tabs necessary and what they will do if they are clicked so on.

Next for each viewcontroller I create, I will subclass from this ParentTabBarController so that the tabs are already in. You can add additional functionality or override it depending on your situation.

In your appdelegate pass in a navigation controller and every time push and dismiss the viewcontrollers you created in second step.

Hope this helps..

Comment: And this ParentTabBarController will delegates `UITabBarControllerDelegate`?

Comment: yes. all tab bar functionalities go in ParentTabBarController

Comment: Would be easier to use a toolbar instead of tab bar to achieve what I am looking for, or is the same effort?

Comment: it depends on your need. tabbar will change the whole view but toolbar is used for one functionality.

Comment: I can customise the view of that toolbar to look like tab bar as every button will have one and standard functionality.